# Make listview scrollbar scroll past end of text

Tags: c#, user-controls, wndproc, scrollbars

I made a user control that utilizes the listview scrollbar. The scrollbar scrolls just enough in order to show everything. How can I make the scrollbar scroll further?

I do not want padding between the user control that I made and the parent form, but make it almost look like there is an extra line that is blank in my user control. Is this possible?

Comment: `scrolls just enough ... to show everything` It scrolls the LVItems in the LV or scrolls the LV on the UC container?  Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It scrolls the LVItems....If I had the last item as blank, it would have the affect that I'm shooting for. Idk how exactly to explain this or even if it's possible. Like if the listview has items that take up x pixels height wise, the scrollbar scrolls x pixels.....but I need it to scroll x+y pixels....y would just appear as blank pixels